# Keyboard returns wrong keycode for Latin characters

Tags: linux, unicode, linux-device-driver, directfb

I am writing an application that handles key presses using DirectFB v1.4.2 / Linux keyboard driver. I am receiving key codes with wrong values for Latin characters. On pressing character 'a' in USB keyboard, I receive a Unicode value of '0xF601'. But, it seems the Unicode value of Latin character 'a' is different. Please let me know what is going wrong here. Is there any specific setting required to be set in DirectFB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Unicode number F601 is in the Private Use range, i.e. no character has been assigned to in the standard but it can be used by mutual agreement between interested parties. It should not expected to have the same meaning, or any meaning, outside the scope of such agreements. So I think you should first check whether the data is really meant to be interpreted as a Unicode number and not as some other code.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that Latin charset 'a-z / A-Z' codes are predefined and keyboard have to honor this and send the Unicode of the respective character. Or is there anything missing in DirectFB configuration that the keycode conversion (0xF601 to 'a') is not happenning.
Thanks.

Comment: Key codes are key codes, not character codes. Ponder what e.g. the Home and function keys should transmit if it were so.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that the default keymapentry for my keyboard is missing. Could someone point me to a sample keymap entry that has to be fed to DirectFB? I tried hard and couldn't find any map file. Thanks!